# Update previous records in MySQL when new records are inserted

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-update

```
CREATE TABLE patients(
    s_no INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    booking_code VARCHAR(64),
    patient_id INT(5),
    visit_count INT(5)
);

INSERT INTO patients (booking_code, patient_id, visit_count) VALUES
('AB103', 3,5),
('AB432', 4,2),
('AB987', 5,1),
('AB733', 6,3),
('AB111', 7,2),
('AB212', 8,4);

INSERT INTO patients (booking_code, patient_id, visit_count) VALUES
('AB734', 4,2),
('AB601', 6,3),
('AB445', 7,2),
('AB389', 8,4);
```

What I want is that every time a new record of a booking is added and if the patient_id already has booked with us previously then his visit_count in his earlier records should update to his latest visit_count inserted in the new record.
Please note that this is an analytics db and its denormalised for easier analytics and dashboarding code.
[image: This is how it gets added. Patient_id 4 , 6 , 7 ,8 have a new records with updated visit_counts in their latest bookings. But i want their visit_count to update in their previous records as well.]

[image: Like in this second image]

Comment: Trigger cannot solve - it cannot alter the row other than current one in the table. Use stored procedure and 2 queries within the transaction in it.

Comment: Your table is referred to as `patient` but in practice it stores the junction information between patient and booking. Hence you shouldn't store the info of total bookings amount in this table because this data is an attribute of the patient, not of a link between patient and definite booking.

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I have removed the visit_count column from the patient table. Now i use views to view the same patient table but with with freshly calculated visit_count in the last column. This way i dont have to worry about updating this column values.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that the best way to get the updated visit_count coulmn is to fetch it using views.

'''
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW patient_info AS SELECT booking_code, patient_id, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patients WHERE patient_id = p.patient_id)AS visit_count FROM patients p;
SELECT * FROM patient_info;
'''